# Not able to Sign in to the mimik developer console in raspbian

Tags: edgeengine

I am working on raspbian and I want to use mimik edgeSdk in it. I'm following the Development Setup procedure as in the website. But I'm not able to Sign in to the **mimik developer console**. Getting some error as shown below when I click at the ***go to console*** option.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please clear browser cache and history and try again. You can also try using a different browser.